# Rendering issue with plots in Matlab when exporting in pdf

Tags: matlab, pdf, plot, rendering

I'm trying to plot some graphs in Matlab and I would like export the images in pdf, but when I'm doing this, there are some glitch added to the plots.
For instance, look at this image.

[image]

To the left, we see the figure in Matlab and to the right the exported image to .pdf (from the save as button). The issue is that in the .pdf, I've got some weird shapes, especially at maxima. Does it exist a better way to export figure in .pdf without those aberrations?

I think the issue is comming from the renderer in matlab [image]

when I choose painters, Matlab mess up with the rendering as in the first picture. I don't know if it is possible to add some custom renderer to fix this issue?

Comment: This may be your PDF viewer settings, try turning off any smooth anti-aliasing processing.

Comment: I already tried several PDF viewer but I always see the same issue. Even with another computer.

Comment: use `export_fig` for reliable figure exporting.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use the standard figure of Matlab because I'm using a lot of embedded tools from the figure window directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bad rendering with Matlab and Painters (vector format)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658656/bad-rendering-with-matlab-and-painters-vector-format)