# Bad rendering with Matlab and Painters (vector format)

Tags: matlab, rendering, render, figure

I wonder why I have a very bad rendering when I use the Painters custom renderer in figure Export Setup? 
Look at this image which has used OpenGL:

[image]

and this one, which has used Painters.

[image]

What the hell is going on here?

Comment: Which version of Matlab are you using? I remember there being a bug in the exporter in 2015b-2016a where it messed up line joins.

Comment: I've got the 2014b version

Comment: does it exist a patch to correct that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jagged outline using Matlab 2014b](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302938/jagged-outline-using-matlab-2014b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [bug](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1133611) in 2014b-2015a. The easiest way to fix this is to upgrade to 2015b or newer.

I had a workaround where I used [matlab2tikz](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz) but that took a bit of work for my application.

I don't believe there to be a workaround that can create .png files from Matlab that works on those versions of Matlab (even [export_fig](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) has the same problem).